# How do we get $\biggl|\dfrac{1}{h}\displaystyle{\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{0}+h}} f(t)-f(x_{0})\,dt \biggr| \le \epsilon$ using the provided lemma?

Tags: real-analysis

The following is a lemma and the proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus from Real Analysis with Applications by Davidson and Donsig:

> Lemma. Suppose that $f$ is an integrable function on $[a,b]$ bounded by $M$. Then $$\biggl| \int_{a}^{b} f(t)\,dt \biggr| \le M(b-a)$$
>
> Proof of the Fundamental Theorem:
>
> Let $f$ be bounded by $M$. Fpr $x,y$ in $[a,b]$, use the lemma to compute
>   \begin{align*}
> |F(x)-F(y)| &= \biggl|\int_{a}^{x} f(t)\,dt - \int_{a}^{y} f(t) \,dt \biggr| \\
> &= \biggl|\int_{y}^{x} f(t) \,dt \biggr| \le M|x-y|.
> \end{align*}
>   Hence $F$ is Lipschitz with constant $M$ and thus is continuous.
>
> Now suppose that $f$ is continuous at $x_{0}$. Given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $\delta >0$ so that $|y-x_{0}|<\delta$ implies that $|f(y)-f(x_{0})|<\epsilon$. Then for $|h| < \delta$, compute
>   \begin{align*}
> \biggl|\dfrac{F(x_{0}+h)-F(x_{0})}{h} -f(x_{0}) \biggr|&=\biggl|\dfrac{1}{h}\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{0}+h} f(t)\,dt - \dfrac{1}{h}\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{0}+h} f(t)-f(x_{0})\,dt \biggr|\\
> &=\biggl|\dfrac{1}{h}\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{0}+h} f(t)-f(x_{0})\,dt \biggr| \le \epsilon. 
> \end{align*}
>   The lemma was used again for the final inequality. Thus
>   \begin{align*}
> F'(x_{0})=\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{F(x_{0}+h)-F(x_{0})}{h}=f(x_{0})
> \end{align*}

How do we use the given lemma to get $\biggl|\dfrac{1}{h}\displaystyle{\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{0}+h}} f(t)-f(x_{0})\,dt \biggr| \le \epsilon$? It would be helpful if someone could elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\left| \frac{1}{h} \int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}f(t) - f(x_0) \,\mathrm{d}t \right|  
&\leq \frac{1}{h} \int_{x_0}^{x_0+h} \left| f(t) - f(x_0) \right| \,\mathrm{d}t   \\
&< \frac{1}{h} \int_{x_0}^{x_0+h} \varepsilon \,\mathrm{d}t  \\
&= \frac{1}{h} (x_0+h-x_0)\varepsilon  \\
&= \varepsilon  \text{.} 
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the integral version of the triangle inequality:
$$\left|\int_a^b g(t)\,dt\right|\le \int_a^b |g(t)|dt.$$
Let $g(t)=f(t)-f(x_0)$. We know that when $|h|<\delta$ and $t\in [x_0,x_0+h]$ we have $|f(t)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

$|f(t)-f(x_{0})|<\epsilon$ for all $t$ in between $x_{0}$ and $x_{0}+h$, so the $\epsilon$ acts as the so called upper bound $M$, and $b-a=(x_{0}+h)-x_{0}=h$.